# Custom CSS on WordPress parent and child pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Believe me, I have searched for an answer to this for several days straight. I believe the answer is simple but I can't get it to work. I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I've learned how to set css for specific WordPress pages, however what I need to set CSS for WordPress parent pages and their children. While it can be accomplished by including every page to my code I know that there has to be a more efficient way as I have about 20 pages under each parent page.

An example of what I am looking for can be found here: (original site)
[www.viewmonthealth.com](https://www.viewmonthealth.com/)

Where I am trying to accomplish this: [www.notthemama.net/prime/](http://notthemama.net/prime/)

Each main link leads to a different section with separate css.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php if (is_page('imaging')) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/viewmont-imaging.css" type="text/css">
<?php } elseif (is_page('labs')) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/viewmont-labs.css" type="text/css">
<?php } else { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
<?php } ?>
```

This works perfectly for pages. I just need to include the parent pages (what I have now) AND child pages (imaging/forms.php). How can I do this? Any help is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing with the parent id

```
function is_child($pageID) { 
    global $post; 
    if( is_page() && ($post->post_parent==$pageID) ) {
               return true;
    } else { 
               return false; 
    }
}
```

putting this in your function and

```
<?php if (is_child(12)) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/viewmont-imaging.css" type="text/css">
<?php } elseif (is_child(14)) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/viewmont-labs.css" type="text/css">
<?php } else { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
<?php } ?>
```

hope this is what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Someone else just pointed me to exactly this and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: hah may be some1esle will be benifited from this one. you already solve it. and mark your question as solved and how it was solved. that will help other too. get help and help other :).

Answer (score 0):

A much leaner approach is to use the following conditional check, there is really no need for a custom function:

```
if ( $post->post_parent == 2 ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/viewmont-imaging.css" type="text/css">
<?php } ?>
```